# TYPO3 - Missing 'detail' path in own extension with list & detail view to deactivate in fixedPostVars of realurl

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I've create a small extension with switchableControllerActions in a FlexForm for List & Detail View.

```
-Cars[12]
--Detail[19]
```

All actions (Car->list;Car->show;Car->new;Car->edit;Car->create;Car->update;Car->delete) are working ... yet when I hover hover the links in the list view or go in Detail View ... I'm missing the /cars/detail/... part of the link:

```
/cars/?tx_ffscarexample_carlist[car]=2&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[action]=show&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[controller]=Car&cHash=ab35fe1werwerssydsdf
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By default Extbase uses the same page for every action, so you will stay on the page with the list view if you just put `<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{car:car}">Link</f:link.action>` in your Fluid template. You need to set the page uid where you want to show the detail view with `<f:link.action action="show" pageUid="[uidOfTheDetailPage]" arguments="{car:car}">Link</f:link.action>`
2. To get rid of the additional `/cars/` in the URL you need to use `fixedPostVars` instead of `postVarSets`. See: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#fixedpostvars

Comment: Great! With pageUid I get the correct links for the show, new, edit, create, update & delete actions. But not for the list action. Here I still get this link: /cars/?tx_ffscarexample_carlist[action]=list&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[controller]=Car&cHash=23d56sdf27c27sdfc2cc1e353c7e Any hint why? I updated above

Comment: Where do you want to have the list view? On the list page I think?